# Bash script different output when doubleclick vs. run in terminal

Tags: bash

I have this script (among others) that generates my wallpaper upon every login/midnight. It has 755 permissions. Part of code:

```
#/bin/bash

convert -size 1440x900 xc:none wall.png
composite -gravity center ../pics/im256.png wall.png wall.png
composite -geometry 118x67+661+578 ../pics/im-title-white.png wall.png wall.png

TIME=`$HOME/bin/time.py | grep "\."`

if [[ $TIME == *\'* ]]
then
    # <...1...>
else
    # <...2...>
fi
```

I'm interested if my `$TIME` variable has `'` symbols in it. When there are no `'` symbols - everything is good.

Now when I know there is at least one `'` symbol (or I can force make that way), when I double-click the script I find myself in `else` statement, when I run the script in terminal - I find myself in `then` statement. I would like to always get to `then` statement, but how?

I cropped the part that is failing (left - correct, right - wrong):

[image: correct image] [image: wrong picture]

Comment: I'm upvoting and voting-to-close at the same time, because actually it's a valid and complete question, with a helpful title. It's just that the issue was very minor. Nevertheless, it's a nice reminder that shell and graphical environments really invoke the scripts in a bit different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me to write a post until I notice that shebang is not actually a shebang. `#!/bin/bash` fixed the problem.

It appears that incorrect shebang defaulted to `/bin/sh` which was incapable of running correctly. My login shell is `/bin/bash` which means running from shell even without `bash` keyword eg.: `./script.sh` defaults to bash and not sh. Why couldn't it do the same on double-click..

Comment: Elaborate your answer, and accept it if it solved the problem.

Comment: Tried it: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Oh, you are right. :) You should still add some clear-up to your answer, pointing out what the problem / mistake was, so others can learn from it.